# Слои - позиционирование

Tags: позиционирование, html, css, html5

**Доброго времени суток!**
Я только начал изучать html и css, у меня есть вопрос, который я самостоятельно решить не могу:

У меня есть div-тело, который я
выровнял по центру страницы(для
корректного отображения на разных
мониторах). Каким образом можно
реализовать наложение множества
div-ов внутри
div-тела(картинки-ссылки) таким образом, чтобы они не были на одном слое?
Максимум, что у меня получилось - расставить их как блоки в одном слое поверх div-тела.

Comment: @kosikhin1996, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно наложить один слой над другим, то нужен z-index, чем выше значение, темы выше слой.

`.one-l{z-index: 1;} .tree-l{z-index: 3;}` и т.д., но если к блоку применить `position:static; или position absolute;`, он будет поверх любого z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вам нужен z-index. Но он работает только если position не равен static. А вообще выложенный код очень помогает понять в чем суть вопроса :)

Answer (score 0):

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```

Попробуйте таким способом. ) Не мешало бы увидеть код. )